# How to append an element to a list based on the condition that a key value exists or not?

Tags: python

I have a Dictionary which contains elements such as

```
'Metadata/Location/Room'
'Metadata/Location/Building'
```

Before appending a new list with these values I need to check if the key ('Metadata/Location/Room') exits in my dict or not (for each entry).

How do I traverse my dict, check if the key exists, and then append it to a new list ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Dictionaries contain items composed of keys and values, so your description of the elements in the Dictionary is incomplete. It's also not clear what list you want to append values to and the source of these values. Please [edit] your question and add this information and show the code you have written to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: What @martineau says. Please show us your actual dictionary. And clarify if *"appending a new list with these values"* means append a list of keys to a dict, a list of values to a dict, or create a list separate to the dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into `try`, `except KeyError` exception-handling:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> 
>>> for key in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
...     try:
...         d[key] += 1
...     except KeyError:
...         print("'%s' not in the dictionary" % key)
... 
'c' not in the dictionary
```

You'll just have to adapt that for keeping (`append`ing) a key if it's in the list. Something like:

```
to_keep = []
try:
    to_keep.append(key)
except KeyError:
    pass
```